# TSQL - Get the difference between each row value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I am storing data in the following table -

> ```
>  [dbo].[readings]
>
>   [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
>   [device_id] [int] NOT NULL,
>   [time] [datetime] NOT NULL,     
>   [reading] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
>   [shift_id] [int] NULL,
> ```

The value is being stored in reading column. What i want is the difference of reading between each row. i.e. if row1 has reading = 1520 and row2 has reading = 1560 then difference should be 40 and so on for row2 and row3 ..... 
The sample data is as below ....

```
67118   5   2013-02-23 04:21:45.107 1.00    42
67119   5   2013-02-23 04:21:45.247 4.00    42
67120   5   2013-02-23 04:21:45.340 7.00    42
67121   5   2013-02-23 04:21:45.433 9.00    42
67122   5   2013-02-23 04:21:45.527 11.00   42
67123   5   2013-02-23 04:21:45.620 13.00   42
67124   5   2013-02-23 04:21:45.713 16.00   42
67125   5   2013-02-23 04:21:45.807 18.00   42
67126   5   2013-02-23 04:21:45.900 20.00   42
67127   5   2013-02-23 04:21:45.993 22.00   42
67128   5   2013-02-23 04:21:46.087 24.00   42
67129   5   2013-02-23 04:21:46.183 26.00   42
67130   5   2013-02-23 04:21:46.277 28.00   42
67131   5   2013-02-23 04:21:46.370 30.00   42
67132   5   2013-02-23 04:21:46.463 31.00   42
67133   5   2013-02-23 04:21:46.557 33.00   42
67134   5   2013-02-23 04:21:46.650 35.00   42
67135   5   2013-02-23 04:21:46.743 37.00   42
67136   5   2013-02-23 04:21:46.837 39.00   42
67137   5   2013-02-23 04:21:46.930 41.00   42
67138   5   2013-02-23 04:21:47.023 43.00   42
67139   5   2013-02-23 04:21:47.117 45.00   42
67140   5   2013-02-23 04:21:47.210 47.00   42
67141   5   2013-02-23 04:21:47.303 49.00   42
67142   5   2013-02-23 04:21:47.400 50.00   42
67143   5   2013-02-23 04:21:47.493 52.00   42
67144   5   2013-02-23 04:21:47.600 55.00   42
67145   5   2013-02-23 04:21:47.693 56.00   42
67146   5   2013-02-23 04:21:47.790 58.00   42
67147   5   2013-02-23 04:21:47.883 60.00   42
```

Further more i need data per day per shift per hours like below. I have written stored procedure and generated the sample data..

```
2013-02-23  1st 4   5   391.00  1.00    390.00
2013-02-23  1st 7   5   2762.00 1019.00 1743.00
2013-02-23  2nd 8   5   3270.00 2764.00 506.00
2013-02-23  3rd 16  5   6255.00 4102.00 2153.00
```

Comment: And you've tried what queries?

Comment: And version of SQL Server?

Comment: For the second part, you need to at least provide column headings for that dataset and an explanation of `shift per hours`.

Comment: Hey Marc thanks for the info. Below is the answer for my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning first question in SQLServer 2005+ you can try this

```
;WITH cte AS
 (  
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY [time]) AS NId
  FROM [dbo].[readings]
  )
  SELECT c1.[id], c1.[device_id], c1.[time], 
         c1.reading AS currRow, ISNULL(c2.reading, 0) AS nextRow,
         c1.reading - ISNULL(c2.reading, c1.reading) AS diff
  FROM cte c1 LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c1.device_id = c2.device_id 
                                    AND c1.NId + 1 = c2.NId
```

Comment: Hey Alexander,I think you are 99.99% close. Tomorrow morning i will give it a try. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hey Alexander, I came into new problem and i have asked for solution at this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064775/the-difference-between-each-row-value-sum-error